# Error: task 1 failed - "there is no .Internal function 'lengths'"

Tags: r

When I run my code in R studio, I don't get any error. However, when I run the same code in HPC cluster in bash I get this error:   `task 1 failed - "there is no .Internal function 'lengths'"`. The version I am running in cluster is `version 3.1.3`, whereas in R studio it is `version 3.2`. Is this causing the error? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: `lengths` is a `base` function. Corrupted R installation?

Comment: Yes, the R version is the cause. `lengths` was introduced in R 3.2. Either upgrade or change your script by defining `lengths<-function(x) vapply(x,length,1L)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that surprising as `lenghts` was introduced in version `3.2` as per the [changelog](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS):

> CHANGES IN R 3.2.0:
>
> NEW FEATURES:
>
> - New lengths() function for getting the lengths of all elements in
>       a list.

Comment: That's the cause for sure as I mentioned in the comments. However, I am a bit worried about the error message he got. Is he calling `.Internal(lengths(...))` in the code instead of just `lengts(...)`? Was someone aware of the missing function and just redefined `lengths` as it is in R 3.2?

Comment: @Pascal Yes, I know. I was wandering about the error message. If you run for instance `lengths(object)` on a R 3.1, you should receive an error of the kind `function not found` instead of the actual message OP reported, since the function doesn't exist in R 3.1. On the other hand, if the guy who wrote the code was aware of the problem, he might have thought to solve by copy/pasting the R 3.2 definition of `lengths` in the code (or by calling `.Internal(lengths)` directly).

Comment: @nicola  Sorry to disturb.